# Prettify search URL

Tags: search, routes

I can't find a way to clean up the search address from
`/search/?q=.../` to `/search/query/`.

I see ways of getting the last segment of the url with something like `craft.request.getSegment`. My other permalinks work fine, but for search I can't get the search template to pickup the `/query/` bit (results in a logical 404 page).

So either it's my .htaccess (using the one provided) missing something. Or alter something else.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to setup the routes for your search URLs.

In this case I’d recommend to use an advanced route with a regular expression, as it allows to use patterns that will ignore the slashes between your search terms. You’d setup the route in your craft/config/routes.php file (see [Advanced Routing](https://craftcms.com/docs/routing#advanced-routing) in the Craft docs).

```php
return array(
    'search/(?P<query>.+)' => 'search/_result',
);
```

This route matches all URLs which start with `search/`, populates a variable named `query` with everything that comes after the `search/` and routes the request to a template search/_result.html.

In your template you can now use the `split` filter to get the individual words. You can then join them to a nice search string for your criteria model (see [Search Syntax](https://craftcms.com/docs/searching) in the docs).

```
{% set words = query|split('/') %}
{% set searchParam = words|join(' OR ') %}
```

Using this Twig code you’d prepare a search string that finds elements containing “advanced” or “routes” for an example URL http://example.com/search/advanced/routes.

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm! Learned something new :)

Answer (score 3):

If you go to `Settings > Routes` in the CP you're able to add routes with wildcard characters like:

```
/search/*
```

and then point that to a template.

You can also [register site routes](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#registerSiteRoutes) in a plugin if you want to go down that route (no pun intended)